# Hide line highlighting in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, rubymine

I just started using one of the JetBrains IntelliJ based IDEs (RubyMine) but I find the line highlighting really distracting. See pics below. Any way to turn it off?

[image: http://luka.s3.amazonaws.com/Screen+Shot+2013-05-30+at+11.57.32.png]
[image: http://luka.s3.amazonaws.com/Screen+Shot+2013-05-30+at+11.57.50.png]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you are referring to the active caret row highlighting, it can be configured in the `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts` settings:

[image: caret row]

Answer (score 0):

In the updated version, first, you need to go in the `preferences`,

[image]

Then, as suggested earlier, need to turn off the background of the `Caret row`,

[image]